# NGINX extract last part of url

Tags: nginx

In my config file, I need to extract the last part of a url into a variable for use in a redirect e.g. if the url is http://www.example.com/question, I need "question" so that I can set up a rewrite. How can I do this please?

Comment: That is called the path, and it is not the last part of a URL. A query string and fragment may follow it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be achieved as follows:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
  set  $last_path_component  $1;
}
```

You can then use the $last_path_component var anywhere you wish. Note this regex will return everything after the last / which could include in url arguments, so if you do not need them, you will have to modify the regex above accordingly.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression submatches --

```
rewrite ^(.*) http://host.example.com$1 permanent;
```

With [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), the parentheses are [metacharacters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter) that groups text into capture blocks.  The first parenthesis will be grouped into $1, the second into $2, and so on.

Comment: For the example in the answer it would be more appropriate to use `$request_uri` i.e.: `rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri permanent;` or better still `location /whatever { return http://example.com$request_uri; }`.